# What is the proper way to align UITableViewCells when only some have an imageView?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview, ios4

I am new to iPhone programming and working on my first real application (i.e. one not written in a book or online) and I've run into a small problem which I could solve a multitude of ways, but feel like there should be a good solution that perhaps I am just missing.

Here is the scenario: I have a `UITableView` with a bunch of standard `UITableViewCell`s in it. What I want to do is toggle a green check mark when the cell is selected and I have that part working (**note:** I'm already using the `accessoryType` for something else, so I can't use it for the checkmark...besides, it's not as pretty). Unfortunately, when I toggle the checkmark like so:

```
if (...) {
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"];
} else {
  cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

It makes the cell's label bounce back and forth depending on whether it is checked or not. What is the proper way to align the cell's text (set via `cell.textLabel.text`) regardless of whether or not it has an image set? The solutions I have come up with are:

1. Create a blank 40x40 png image in Photoshop and set the unchecked to that
2. Create a blank 40x40 image solely in code
3. Set some setting that I don't know about that will align it for me
4. Create a subclass of UITableCellView that does what I need (which would be stupid, I'd just go with option 1...)

Suggestions? Thoughts? Comments? Thank you very much :-)

P.S. I'd like the solution to work with OS 3.0 and 4.0 if that makes any sort of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the way to go for a standard cell.

Strictly speaking, you do not have to subclass UITableViewCell to customize the layout.  You can add any views you wish to the contentView.  So you can add a UILabel and UIImageView to the contentView instead of using the imageView and textLabel properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Shaji - Thanks for the comment, that question may help in the future.